# Using cor() on the entire data set versus two variables in R

Tags: r, correlation, stat

I have a dataset called "metals" with many variables and I want to look at each pair's spearman correlation rho. When I run `cor(metals, method = "spearman", use = "complete.obs")`, I get a value for, lets say, metal1 and metal2 that is .143.

**However**, if I run `cor.test(metals$metal1,metals$metal2, method = "spearman", use = "complete.obs")`, it returns .3529. The same discrepancy appears for all other pairs. Can someone explain why or if there is a fundamental difference between the two methods?

Comment: It has to do with the use of "complete.obs". Complete observations are observations for which you have values for every variable. If you only consider 2 variables, there might be more complete observations. If you set `use` to `parwise.complete.obs`, you should find the same result.

Comment: Thank you so so much!

Comment: The default test method for `cor` is _pearson_. You have used _spearman_ for `cor.test`. Try changing this to _pearson_ also.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of `cor` does not mention the possibility to use formula as input:

```
Arguments
x   a numeric vector, matrix or data frame.

y   NULL (default) or a vector, matrix or data frame with compatible dimensions to x. The default is equivalent to y = x (but more efficient).
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant `cor.test(metals$metal1,metals$metal2, method = "spearman", use = "complete.obs")`. (Although the documentation for `cor` does say that we can give both x and y values)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by the different test methods used.
`cor` uses *pearson*, your have used *spearman* for `cor.test`.

Have a look to this example from the **Boston** data from the package `MASS`.

```r
# library(MASS)
boston <- MASS::Boston

round(cor(boston),2)
#> not shown

round(cor(boston[1:2]),2)
#>      crim   zn
#> crim  1.0 -0.2
#> zn   -0.2  1.0


# The spearman-version of cor.test
cor.test(boston$crim, boston$zn, method = 'spearman') ->s
#> Warning in cor.test.default(boston$crim, boston$zn, method = "spearman"): Cannot
#> compute exact p-value with ties
s$estimate
#>        rho 
#> -0.5716602

# The pearson-version of cor.test
cor.test(boston$crim, boston$zn, method = 'pearson') -> p
p$estimate
#>        cor 
#> -0.2004692
```